# Why does xLearn fit function causes kernel crashes in Jupyter?

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, classification

I'm trying to make CTR (Click through rate) prediction using a python module named 'xlearn'.
It enables me to implement a FFM (field-aware factorisation machine) quite easily.

However, I have a problem with the fit function ( supposed to train the model) which crashes the kernel of my jupyter notebook without any error messages.

Here is the code :

```py
import xlearn as xl
ffm_model = xl.create_ffm() 

param = {'task':'binary', 'lr':0.2, 'lambda':0.002, 'metric':'acc'}

ffm_model.setTrain('ffm_train.txt')

ffm_model.fit(param, "./model.out")  #this line crashes the kernel
```

I've already tried to fit the model just after `python ffm_model = xl.create_ffm()` this also crashes the kernel without any error messages ...

Don't hesitate to share your ideas I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize the xLearn module was showing error messages in the terminal :
[Xlearn Imgae Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDm0S.png)